# Recursive reflectance in ray tracer not working

Tags: java, recursion, reflection, raytracing

for some reason in my ray tracer if I try to limit the number of recursive calls in my ray tracer my reflectance doesn't work.

Here is my reflectance code:

```
public static int recursionLevel;
public int maxRecursionLevel;
public Colour shade(Intersection intersection, ArrayList<Light> lights, Ray incidenceRay) {
    recursionLevel++;
    if(recursionLevel<maxRecursionLevel){
        Vector3D reflectedDirection = incidenceRay.direction.subtractNormal(intersection.normal.multiply(2).multiply(incidenceRay.direction.dot(intersection.normal)));

        Ray reflectiveRay = new Ray(intersection.point, reflectedDirection);

        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Colour tempColour = new Colour();

        for(int i = 0; i<RayTracer.world.worldObjects.size(); i++){
            Intersection reflectiveRayIntersection = RayTracer.world.worldObjects.get(i).intersect(reflectiveRay);
            if (reflectiveRayIntersection != null && reflectiveRayIntersection.distance<min){
                min = reflectiveRayIntersection.distance;
                recursionLevel++;
                tempColour = RayTracer.world.worldObjects.get(i).material.shade(reflectiveRayIntersection, lights, reflectiveRay);
                recursionLevel--;
            }

        }

        return tempColour;
    }else{
        return new Colour(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    }

}
```

If I get rid of the if statement it works, though I run out of memory if I place too many reflective objects. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `recursionLevel` as global state, but it really should be local state. Also, with every recursive call to `shade()`, you're incrementing it twice and only decrementing it once. I would refactor your code as follows:

- Delete the `recursionLevel` global
- Add a `recursionLevel` parameter to your `shade()` method
- Keep your `if(recursionLevel < maxRecursionLevel)` check
- Remove the `recursionLevel` increments and decrements around the recursive call to `shade()`
- Modify the recursive call to `shade()` such that it calls `shade(..., recursionLevel + 1)`